# Laravel Validation Error Message required_if not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am validating a form using Laravel 5.2

using validation check `required_if` for input `youtube-embed`. validation takes place successfully but the custom error message does not work. Here is the code maybe some one can take a look.

```
$messages = [
        'youtube-embed.required_if' => 'Please paste in your youtube embed code',
    ];

$this->validate($request, [
        'youtube-embed'      => 'required_if:youtube,on',
    ]);
```

This is the error message that laravel is returning instead of my custom error:

```
The youtube-embed field is required when youtube is on.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->validate($request, 
    ['youtube-embed'      => 'required_if:youtube,on',], 
    ['required_if' => 'Please paste in your youtube embed code',]
);
```

Basically you can pass your custom messages as third parameter in validate function.

Comment: Worked!  Thank you very much! Was trying to fix this for an hour before I posted this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'payout_method' => 'required:in,bankTransfer,paypal',
        'paypal_email'  => 'required_if:payment_type,paypal|email',
        'receiver'      => 'required_if:payment_type,bankTransfer|max:45',
        'iban'          => 'required_if:payment_type,bankTransfer|max:45|iban',
        'bic'           => 'required_if:payment_type,bankTransfer|max:15|bic',
    ];

    return $rules;
}

/**
 * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'payout_method.required'   => trans('validation.attributes.payout_type_required'),
        'paypal_email.required_if' => trans('validation.attributes.paypal_email_required'),
        'paypal_email.email'       => trans('validation.attributes.paypal_email_invalid'),
        'iban.required_if'         => trans('validation.attributes.bank_account_required'),
        'bic.required_if'          => trans('validation.attributes.bank_swift_required'),
        'iban.iban'                => trans('validation.attributes.bank_account_invalid'),
        'bic.bic'                  => trans('validation.attributes.bank_swift_invalid'),
    ];
}
```

what i can do in this case? Laravel return 'The paypal email field is required.' for other fields this work, only not work with required_if

Answer (score 0):

If your'e using the `Request` class:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'youtube-embed.required' => 'Your custom message here.',
    ];
}
```

Works on `Laravel 7`

Comment: Looks like as of Laravel 8, using required_if works as expected, and alternatively will not fall back on required as mentioned previously: